# Ubuntu 16-04 LTS update = no more SD cards mounting

Tags: updates, sd-card

When mounting the cards, I get:

> Error mounting /dev/sdd1 at /media/giemastruc/PVCNC: Command-line `mount -t "vfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,utf8=1,showexec,flush" "/dev/sdd1" "/media/giemastruc/PVCNC"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error"

This happens with different card readers.

Update : I did the 18.04 LTS upgrade with no changes. It looks like something is desactivated during first 16.04 lts update. I lost my DVD burner too :(

```
sudo lsusb : 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 1ea7:0064  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 046d:c225 Logitech, Inc. G11/G15 Keyboard / G keys
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 05e3:0749 Genesys Logic, Inc. <<< the SD card reader
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c221 Logitech, Inc. G11/G15 Keyboard / Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c223 Logitech, Inc. G11/G15 Keyboard / USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

sudo lsblk :
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    87M  1 loop /snap/core/5145
loop1    7:1    0 151,4M  1 loop /snap/arduino-mhall119/5
loop2    7:2    0  42,1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/701
loop3    7:3    0   3,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
loop4    7:4    0 140,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop5    7:5    0  87,9M  1 loop /snap/core/5328
loop6    7:6    0  87,9M  1 loop /snap/core/5548
loop7    7:7    0 128,8M  1 loop /snap/arduino-mhall119/3
loop8    7:8    0  14,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop9    7:9    0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/124
loop10   7:10   0   2,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/238
loop11   7:11   0  87,8M  1 loop /snap/jgalaxian/14
loop12   7:12   0   4,7M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/49
sda      8:0    0 223,6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 107,8G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     4G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 107,8G  0 part /
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
sdc      8:32   0 186,3G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 186,3G  0 part /media/giemastruc/Auxilliaire
sr0     11:0    1     2K  0 rom
```

Comment: Had that issue but it fixed itself. Could have been a kernel release that didn't like my built-in card-reader or its driver. Currently on 4.15.0-33.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback xenoid. Actually, I did some sudo apt-get update and several reboots, but cards still not want to mount. I can see them through but as I want to mount one I get :
"Error mounting /dev/sdd1 at /media/giemastruc/PVCNC: Command-line `mount -t "vfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,utf8=1,showexec,flush" "/dev/sdd1" "/media/giemastruc/PVCNC"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error"

Comment: Add this to your question...

Comment: I tried with various car readers, and I get the same issue :/

Comment: sudo lsusb<br/>
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub<br/>
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub<br/>
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub<br/>
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub<br/>
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1ea7:0064  <br/>
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub<br/>
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 05e3:0749 Genesys Logic, Inc. <br/>
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c221 Logitech, Inc. G11/G15 Keyboard / Keyboard<br/>

Comment: Plz add this, properly formatted, to you initial question.